# question about j-invariant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, elliptic-curves

In [Hartshorne](http://books.google.com/books?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&pg=PA317), there's a formula for the j-invariant in terms of $\lambda$. It says that $$ j = 2^8 \frac{(\lambda^2-\lambda+1)^3}{\lambda^2(\lambda-1)^2}.$$ Can one reverse this formula? That is, can we express $\lambda$ in terms of $j$?

Of course, there will be six different solutions because we are dealing with a  polynomial in $\lambda$ of degree six.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in, [see here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=j%3D2%5E8%2A%28x%5E2-x-1%29%5E3%2Fx%5E2%2F%28x-1%29%5E2).

Comment: I'm very interested but...there's no link?

Comment: Roots are rather difficult.

Comment: Yeah I can see. Thnx anyway!

Comment: This is not an answer ! I don't understand why such an answer has been validated !